# The version of CocoaPods used to generate the lockfile (1.5.3) is higher than the version of the current executable (1.5.2)

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, podfile-lock

on `$pod install` it gives warning & fails

*[The version of CocoaPods used to generate the lockfile (1.5.3) is higher than the version of the current executable (1.5.2)](https://github.com/pawarvijay/pod-install-error/blob/master/README.md)*

What is it trying to say ?

macOs : 10.11.6 osx el capitan

my pod version is : 1.5.**3**

What does"current executable" (1.5.**2**) means ?

and

how to update it ?

Comment: You will need to update your pod.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

The error you are getting is due to your podfile.lock being built with an older version of Cocoapods. All you need to do is to delete your podfile.lock file and run `pod install`. This will create a new podfile.lock, with your current dependencies. Note that it should not take too long because your files should already be downloaded, they just need to be linked in said file.

Comment: I don't know if this was just an issue for me or but the `podfile.lock` but while it was being tracked through git it wasn't part of the Xcode project so I had to delete it through terminal.

Comment: @Honey the Podfile.lock is usually not included in your Xcode file structure, but can usually be found in your project's root directory in Finder

Comment: Careful, this has the unintended consequences of upgrading all of your pods if you had not version locked them in your Podfile.

Comment: It didn't resolved to me..

Comment: I tried the above suggestion and check the pod version, it still remains the same.

Comment: @DiggyJohn If following best practices of [12 factor apps](https://12factor.net) you would not run into this issue. However, you are correct if they are not explicitly declared.

Answer (score 21):

**3 solution**

1. deleted `ios/podfile.lock` and again do `$pod install`

**OR**

2. OS UPDATE

   2.1 updated mac to high sierra or higher

   2.2 update xcode

   2.3 then update pod $sudo gem install cocoapods

   2.4 then `$cd ios`

   2.5 then `$pod install`

**OR**

3. do any thing to make version match, then only it will work

Comment: Tried both answers and neither are working for me...any other ideas?

Comment: @JoshuaHart do all the things to make version match, then only it will work , I only remember 2

Comment: @JoshuaHart, if nothing else works, try a pod deintegrate and then a pod install.

Answer (score 6):

For those like me whose cocoapods version is 1.5.2, you can update cocoapods using

`sudo gem install cocoapods`

and the problem is solved

For checking pod version use

`pod --version`

For those for which cocoapods version is 1.5.3, you can delete podfile.lock and do `pod install`. However please note that if the version, of libraries used in your project, is not specified in podfile, then they will be automatically updated to latest vesrion.

Comment: `sudo gem install cocoapods` worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
$ [sudo] gem install cocoapods
```

you can update with this command

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When answering an older question with existing answers it is useful to point out what new aspect of the question your answer addresses. It appears that your answer was already included by one of the other existing answers.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, I updated my `cocoacpods` version and it worked.

If you previously installed `cocoapods` using `brew`

1. You need to update your local installation of `cocoapods`, you can run:

   ```
    brew install cocoapods
   ```
2. Once installed hen run

   ```
   pod install
   ```

If you previously installed `cocoapods` using `gem`:

1. You need to update your local installation of `cocoapods`, you can run:

   ```
    sudo gem install cocoapods
   ```
2. Once installed you can generate your new `Podfile.lock` matching the new version by running:

   ```
   pod install
   ```

You might have to also sometimes upgrade your `ruby` version if it does not work with the `cocaopods` version you installed you can use [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) to upgrade your `ruby` version to the one compatible with your cocaopods.

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried the above methods and it doesn't work, then try this way:

```py
gem update --system
```

Answer (score -2):

> $ sudo gem install cocoapods

you can solve

Comment: Please highlight the additional insight this answer provides, in comparison to existing older answers. Currently it gives an impression of only repeating the code of a different answer, but with even less explanation. The helpfulness of this answer is hence quite non-obvious.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain how this line solves the problem and how it improves on the existing upvoted answers the question already has, so that it is useful for users with similar issues.