# Flutter: Add plugin only for iOS in pubspec.yaml file

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there any way to add a plugin only for a particular platform (like just for iOS) in `pubspec.yaml` file?

Something like this.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  isIos ? http: ^1.0 : null
```

**PS**: I also know I can import the plugin normally and in code, I can make changes but I don't want this solution.

```
if (Theme.of(context).platform != TargetPlatform.iOS) {
  // don't use that plugin part
}
```

I simply don't want to add plugin in my `pubspec.yaml` for a particular platform. Possible?

Comment: Nope, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55567988/flutter-audio-service-dependancy-issue-in-ios (but there may be a possible hack, posted there)

Answer (score 2):

For the pubspec.yaml, you wouldn't be able to specify the platform under dependencies: so

```
dependencies:
   flutter:
    sdk: flutter
   http: ^1.0
```

Then inside your dart code,

```
import 'dart:io';

if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  //code here will run only when device is android
} else if (Platform.isIOS) {
  //code here will run only when device is iOS
}
```

Comment: That won't work if the package is preventing the build. I am trying to use meta_seo, but I am having a hard time finding a way of having the same source code for web and for Android (excluding the package)

Answer (score -1):

Adding a plugin for only a specific platform is not possible. There is an easier way to access the current platform though.

```
import 'dart:io';


if(Platform.isIOS) {
 // Use plugin
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure, but one possible way around is to install that pod natively and write its implementation in Xcode, and then invoking that native code via the flutter application.